# AWS: Where I can learn AWS Cloud Computing for beginner to Advance level for REST API and Authorisation Deployment, for Free?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have Requirement of developing a REST API with DB on AWS with Our custom Jar, that will be processing the data coming in the request, once processed we will give a response the result comes from our jar.
We have :
Our Java application that will process the data.
Need to develop Authorisation platform for a various client using REST API.
Need to log all the transaction that is requested and how many are rejected and processed successfully.

We are thinking to deploy the complete application on AWS, so I am looking for best study material on developing and Deployment on AWS that is free (budget issue).
Please suggest where should I start as I am a newbie on the cloud platform.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save on cost with AWS, try to go serverless architecture. 
Use:

- S3: to host your front end code by making your bucket a website
- Lambda: to host your backend code to insert and retrive from database. You get 1 million requers free per month
- Api Gateway: it would provide an interface to access lambda function and detailed logging can be done to cloud watch. It also provides with Authorization with API keys and Cognito user pools.
- DynamoDb: it is aws managed database, that give you 15 free read write provisioned throughput

You can start with this 
https://medium.com/byteagenten/serverless-architecture-with-aws-adcaa3415acd?source=linkShare-22ecbac0bdc-1526628767

Comment: Thanks, @Prathamesh, we don't have front-end code, but we have jar file that will process the requested data (like some calculation it would do). So I have one question should be we go with S3 with EC2? and mone more question is will Cognito user in aws allowed as restriction of the user (means I will set up an account for the user and only those user can access that application). User don't have permission to create there authentication, however password they can create there own.

Comment: Few questions:
1) what access mean for user here?

Comment: I don't understand your requirements.Few questions:
1) what would trigger the execution of your job? 2) what access mean for user here?  3) If you have an application, how are you planning to provide an interface to end user, if you dont have front end?

Comment: Access means access to the application deployed over AWS. Execution of Job will be triggered by the REST API (When the user hit the REST API, It will hit the execution of Job), Interface will a REST API.

Comment: So Our Application like that : We have already a java application which do some calculation (but don't have User Interface) Client just take this jar and uses it's exposed function first to get the singleton instance and then call the parameterized function.once they provide argument to that functioin and executes it, they gets result in string.

Comment: Now this application/jar we deploy it on premise. Now we are moving to AWS cloud, and planning to create REST web service that will hit this application and do the calculation then return result in the response. So i don't know how to start.

Comment: So I have questions: 1) In terms of developing web service, how to do it on AWS? 2) There is API gateway and IAM for authentication and authorization of the user, so which will suit best in this Scenario?

Comment: I would still suggest using AWS Lambda. Refactor your Java jar to accept data in the form Lambda accepts. You can have Api gateway in front of lambda, with a cognito for authentication. In Api Gateway, use Your cognito pool as your authorizer. Cognito pool also provides out of box UI for user accounts managment, password change and self signup and login with social providers. You can upload your file to be processed to Lambda, or upload ot to S3 and point Lambda to refer S3.

Comment: If you want to do EC2 route, you will have to manage your own servers, pay hourly for those instances.

Comment: Thanks, - Prathamesh Jagtap, I got the clear picture now. Thanks again :)